# int pointer to char array

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to use the Send_Message() function in the Windows API from C#. I have everything fine except for the last parameter which is WPARAM, which I found in my research is an unsigned int. I'm sending the 0x402 message(SB_GETTEXT) and WPARAM is supposed to represent a pointer to an array of chars in which the text will be put.

This is the code I have

```
    unsafe
    {
        char[] result = new char[40];
        int* ptr = (*int)&result;
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
    Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('char[]')
```

Does it have anything to do with the 'result = new char[40]' part?

Thanks.

Comment: try `StringBuffer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @akonsu: I assume you meant `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @JimMischel of course. sorry.

Comment: Try `char* result = new char[40];`

Comment: Again, could somebody tell me why it was down voted? I can't get better if I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    uint Msg, 
    long wParam, 
    [MarshalAs   (UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder lParam);
```

Note that according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `lParam` is the pointer to the string, not `wParam`, as your question states.

You might also be interested in the description over at pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SB_GETTEXT.html

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I switched lParam and wParam in my mind by mistake.

Comment: @Jim Both lParam and wParam are IntPtr.

Comment: Oh you're right. I thought WPARAM stayed at 32 bits. Is there another common case in Win32 where an argument didn't grow?